# Find and replace but keep original value sorted from time at the end in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have a text that has the time at the end of each row and I would like to keep the time and add a new line after the time and also separate the lines with a ; to be able to imort a CSV file in excel. I had some help with my previous question when the time was in the front but I have tried to move around the expression in `\R(?!\d\d:\d\d|\z)` but no luck.

The text is:

```
Nån Annan Nu - Molly Sandén
Nån Annan Nu
Molly Sandén
22:33
Lay All Your Love On Me - Abba
Lay All Your Love On Me
Abba
14:21
What's Love Got To Do With It - Kygo and Tina Turner
What's Love Got To Do With It
Kygo and Tina Turner
12:47
```

and I would like the result to be

```
Nån Annan Nu - Molly Sandén;Nån Annan Nu;Molly Sandén;22:33
Lay All Your Love On Me - Abba;Lay All Your Love On Me;Abba;14:21
What's Love Got To Do With It - Kygo and Tina Turner;What's Love Got To Do With It;Kygo and Tina Turner;12:47
```

Hopefully someone can help with this and explain how the search and replace expressions function works or help me with a link so I can read ore about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?<!\d\d:\d\d)\R`
- Replace with: `;`
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?<!            # negative lookbehind, make sure we haven't before:
    \d\d:\d\d       # 2 digit-colon-2 digit
)               # end of lookbehind
\R              # any kind of linebreak
```

Comment: thank you so much! There is only one little thing. The result is:

    Nån Annan Nu - Molly Sandén;Nån Annan Nu;Molly Sandén;22:33
    ;Lay All Your Love On Me - Abba;Lay All Your Love On Me;Abba;14:21
    ;What's Love Got To Do With It - Kygo and Tina Turner;What's Love Got To Do With It;Kygo and Tina Turner;12:47

Is there a way to remove the ; at the start of each line?

Comment: @Christer: May be there are some spaces after the digits. use `(?<!\d\d:\d\d)\h*\R`

Comment: No sorry, it is the same result.

Comment: [Works fine for me](https://regex101.com/r/GtLw47/1)